# External Link inside a webform (using master page)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I am trying to get one of the webforms in my application to link to another website, outside of my application. I can get the page to load as a new webpage in my browser easily but I need to keep my masterpage in view.

Can this even be done?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the IFRAME tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" title="Google's Website">
    <!-- Alternate content for non-supporting browsers -->
</iframe >
```